# Como listas sabem comparar meus objetos?

Tags: c#, .net, lista, comparação

Eu tenho uma classe de `Users`, com algumas propriedades básicas dentro dela. Tenho também uma lista `List<User>` que possui alguns usuários cadastrados nela.

Considerando o programa abaixo:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class User {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
    
    public User(string name, int age) { Name = name; Age = age; } 
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<User> users = new () {
            new User("Fernando", 23),
            new User("Roberto", 45)
        };
        
        var alessandra = new User("Alessandra", 27);
        var roberto = new User("Roberto", 45); // < --- idêntico ao que já existe na lista
        
        Console.WriteLine("Coleção contém alessandra? {0}", users.Contains(alessandra));
        users.Add(alessandra);
        Console.WriteLine("Coleção contém alessandra? {0}", users.Contains(alessandra));
        users.Remove(roberto);
        Console.WriteLine("Coleção contém roberto? {0}", users.Contains(roberto));
        
        foreach(User u in users) 
            Console.WriteLine("Nome='{0}' Idade={1}", u.Name, u.Age);
    }
}
```

A saída é:

```
Coleção contém alessandra? False
Coleção contém alessandra? True
Coleção contém roberto? False
Nome='Fernando' Idade=23
Nome='Roberto' Idade=45
Nome='Alessandra' Idade=27
```

Percebemos que Roberto ainda está presente na lista, mesmo após criando um objeto idêntico e removendo ele da coleção logo em seguida. Com Alessandra, após adicionar na lista, o método `Contains()` indica que aquele objeto está na lista imediatamente após adicioná-lo na mesma.

Com isso, percebo que a coleção `users` não está usando os valores do objeto em sua comparação.

Por tanto, o que `List<T>` usa para comparar os objetos que estão presentes na coleção?

Comment: Simples, um objeto "idêntico" não é o mesmo objeto. A comparação entre objetos verifica se recebeu duas referências ao mesmo objeto. Só nesse caso ela retorna `true`. Afinal, é bem comum duas pessoas terem o mesmo primeiro nome e a mesma idade. Mas não é comum serem a mesma pessoa. Eu nunca vi :). Só finalizando, a lista não sabe nada além do tipo dos objetos que tem nela. A lista em si não está envolvida na comparação. Ela é feita entre o argumento do `Contains` e cada elemento individual da lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se não for feito nenhuma personalização e usar uma forma específica de comparar ou se os objetos não possuem uma forma própria de comparar a lista (através do método `Contains()`) por padrão irá analisar se o valor que está gravado nela é igual ao valor que está comparando.

Em objetos com tipos por referência por padrão o valor de comparação é a referência, o tal do ponteiro.

Então o objeto `roberto` tem os mesmos dados que já estavam na lista, mas são objetos completamente diferentes. Se tivesse mandando procurar `roberto` antes de tentar removâ-lo veria que não foi achado, porque a referência do objeto que está nessa variável é diferente da referência do objeto que está na lista.

O método `Remove()` retorna um booleano indicado se ele conseguiu remover o objeto, e se mandar imprimir verá que o retorno foi falso, já que a remoção não aconteceu, por isso depois ele é listado. E não foi removido justamente porque não encontrou um objeto igual, ou seja, não achou dentro da lista o mesmo objeto. Tem como fazer tudo isso melhor:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
var roberto = new User("Roberto", 45);
List<User> users = new () {
    new User("Fernando", 23),
    new User("Roberto", 45),
    roberto
};
var alessandra = new User("Alessandra", 27);
foreach(User u in users) WriteLine($"Nome='{u.Name}' Idade={u.Age}");
WriteLine($"Coleção contém alessandra? {users.Contains(alessandra)}");
users.Add(alessandra);
WriteLine($"Coleção contém alessandra? {users.Contains(alessandra)}");
WriteLine($"Conseguiu remover roberto da variável? {users.Remove(roberto)}");
WriteLine($"Coleção contém roberto? {users.Contains(roberto)}");
foreach(User u in users) WriteLine($"Nome='{u.Name}' Idade={u.Age}");
WriteLine($"Conseguiu remover roberto da variável? {users.Remove(roberto)}");

public class User {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
    public User(string name, int age) { Name = name; Age = age; } 
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1X8hkE). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WISM5M). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/Comparing.cs).

Dá pra brincar mais.

O segundo não remove porque já foi removido, ele não encontra mais o objeto lá. Tem outro parecido, mas é outro objeto.

Pode pensar: "como apagar um dado sem uma variável?". Ou tem que ir na posição dele, ou achar por uma forma de busca até chegar na posição, ou precisa pegar o endereço do objeto que está na lista, que não é simples de fazer porque C# não oferece isso de forma direta, mas tem como obter. Então não consegue com [`Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Se tivesse uma implementação em `User` que tratasse o `Equals()` de maneira específica e analisasse os dados, de preferência algum que seja único, aí a comparação seria outra. Não é que o compilador faria uma escolha, é que o `Euqals()` por padrão chama o `ReferenceEquals()` em tipos por referência, e só sua implementação pode mudar isso, se quiser.

Comment: Se eu sobrecarregar o método `Object.Equals()`, o comparador não irá mais usar referências e sim a sobrecarga que fiz?

Comment: Sim, aí muda tudo e pode comparar pelo conteúdo, por isso eu falei sobre o padrão, você pode mudá-lo. No exemplo específico seria temerário porque pode ter pessoas diferentes com os mesmos dados, mas só pra exercício tudo bem. Na verdade, ele já usa o `Equals()`. Acontece que seu objeto delega para o `ReferenceEquals()`.